# Share kusto variables between grafana panels

Tags: grafana, azure-data-explorer, kql

Well, let's say that I have the query from my previous question: [How to do multi graph time series on Grafana with Kusto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74478232/how-to-do-multi-graph-time-series-on-grafana-with-kusto)

Then I'd like to consume the `tiemposCicloBruto` variable from one panel to another in order to avoid repeating queries.

I saw: https://grafana.com/blog/2020/10/14/learn-grafana-share-query-results-between-panels-to-reduce-load-time/

But there isn't any way to share variables at all...

I also tried it as a dashboard variable, but it doesn't seem to support tabular expressions at all...

Answer (score 0):

You can share only *input* variables across dashboard panels. Variables work as primitive text substitution in one direction (from dashboard to query), and do not take into account any context in your query language.

Your link tells about sharing **results** of the query between different panels. If exact same result set returned to a panel fits your needs, you can reuse it "for free", without putting load on the database. You don't need to save it into any variable, you just set it as a pseudo-datasource and you get the result immediately.

You can factor this feature into design of you panels. Examples could be:

- time series plus histogram visualizations of the same data;
- time-series chart plus a panel with latest readings (or use other Grafana reduce expressions).